# Angular js directive render

Tags: angularjs, render, directive

I'm trying to use the directive uiDateMask but the render don't work someone can help-me? I can't render on mdp-date-picker ... but I render it on input text.

its weird!!!                                                                                                                                                  I apreciate some with this issue

```
<head>

     <meta charset="UTF-8">

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>      

     <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>

     <script src="http://localhost:3000/manutencao-eventos/js/moment/moment.js"></script>

     <script src="http://localhost:3000/manutencao-eventos/js/moment/locale/pt-br.js"></script>

     <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alenaksu/mdPickers/0.7.5/dist/mdPickers.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>







     <script>

         var app =angular.module("prototipo",['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache','ngAria','mdPickers','ngAnimate']);

         app.controller("prototipoCtrl",function($scope,$mdpDatePicker){

                $scope.myDate = new Date();

                $scope.fromDate = new Date();

                $scope.toDate = new Date();



                $scope.currentDate = new Date();

                $scope.showDatePicker = function(ev) {

                        $mdpDatePicker($scope.currentDate, {

                        targetEvent: ev

                    }).then(function(selectedDate) {

                        $scope.currentDate = selectedDate;

                   });;

                };



                $scope.aniversarios = [

                    {"name":"daniel","date":"2016-10-25"},

                    {"name":"maria","date":"2016-10-24"},

                    {"name":"josé","date":"2016-10-23"},

                    {"name":"joão","date":"2016-10-22"}

                ];

         });

         app.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider){

            moment.updateLocale("pt-br",null);



           // $mdDateLocaleProvider.months = moment.months();

           // $mdDateLocaleProvider.shortMonths = moment.monthsShort();

           // $mdDateLocaleProvider.days = moment.weekdays();

           // $mdDateLocaleProvider.shortDays = moment.weekdaysShort();



            //$mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {

            //    return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

            //};

         });



        app.filter("searchDatesBetween", function ($filter) {

            return function (items, from, to) {

                var result = [];



                if (!from || !to) {

                    return items;

                }



                var df = moment(moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

                var dt = moment(moment(to).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                    var dtSemFt = moment(items[i].date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                    var tf = moment(dtSemFt);

                   // console.log('FROM FT > ' + moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ'));

                   // console.log('TO FT > '+ moment(to).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ'));

                   // console.log('FROM FT2 > ' + moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z'));

                   // console.log('TO FT2 > '+ moment(to).format('YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.000Z'));

                  //  console.log('FROM > ' + df);

                   // console.log('TO > '+ dt);

                   // console.log('TF > ' + tf);

                   // console.log('dtSemFtTF > ' + dtSemFt);

                    var isBefore = moment(tf).isSameOrBefore(dt,'day');

                    var isAfter = moment(tf).isSameOrAfter(df, 'day');

                   // console.log('isSameOrBefore: ' + isBefore + ' e isAfter: ' + isAfter);

                    //if (tf >= df && tf <= dt) {

                    if (isBefore && isAfter) {

                        result.push(items[i]);

                    }

                }

                return result;

            };

        });

        app.directive('uiDateMask', function () {
return {
    //propriedade require - Estabelece um vinculo com outra diretiva interagindo
    //por meio do controller, que é um dos parâmetros da funçAo
    //link
    require: "ngModel",
    //propriedade link - executada depois do template ter sido compilado,
    //podemos usar para interagir com a DOM,
    //tratando eventos ou mesmo para definir o comportamento
    //associado com a logica da diretiva.
    //scope - escopo do controlador
    //angular.element - permite fazer uma série de operaçoes com jqLite
    //attrs - nos permite acessar atributos do elemento ex: id,name,value etc
    //ctrl - nos permite acessar o controller defido na propriedade require.
    link: function (scope,element,attrs,ctrl) {
        var _formatDate = function (date) {
            date = date.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,"");
            if(date.length > 2){
                date = date.substring(0,2) + "/" + date.substring(2);
            }
            if(date.length > 5){
                date = date.substring(0,5) + "/" + date.substring(5,9);
            }
            return date;
        };

        element.bind("keyup",function(){
             console.log(ctrl.$viewValue);
            ctrl.$setViewValue(_formatDate(ctrl.$viewValue));
            ctrl.$modelValue = _formatDate(ctrl.$viewValue);
            ctrl.$$rawModelValue = _formatDate(ctrl.$viewValue);
            console.log(ctrl.$viewValue);
            console.log(ctrl);
            console.log(ctrl.$render());
            console.log(ctrl.$viewChangeListeners);
            //console.log(element.html());
            //ctrl.find("input").$render();

            ctrl.$render();
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
     </script>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/docs.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alenaksu/mdPickers/0.7.4/dist/mdPickers.min.css">

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



     <style>

         body {

        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

        }



        #content { height: 100%; }



        #content > md-content {

        background-color: #eee;

        }

     </style>

</head>

<body ng-controller="prototipoCtrl">

    <form name="prototipoForm">

    <div flex-gt-xs="">

        <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>

        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>

    </div>

    {{fromDate}}

    {{$event}}

    <div>

          <h4 class="md-subhead">Using $mdpDatePicker service</h4>

          <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="showDatePicker($event)" aria-label="show picker">show picker</md-button>

          <p>

            {{ currentDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}

          </p>

        </div>

        <div>

          <h4 class="md-subhead">Custom format + error messages</h4>

          <mdp-date-picker mdp-open-on-click required name="dateFormat" mdp-placeholder="My date(dd/mm/yyyy)" mdp-format="DD/MM/YYYY" ng-model="fromDate"></mdp-date-picker>

            <div ng-messages="prototipoForm.dateFormat.$error">

              <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>

          </div>

          <mdp-date-picker mdp-open-on-click required name="dateFormat" mdp-placeholder="My date(dd/mm/yyyy)" mdp-format="DD/MM/YYYY" ng-model="toDate" ui-date-mask></mdp-date-picker>

            <div ng-messages="prototipoForm.dateFormat.$error">

              <div ng-message="required">This is required</div>

          </div>

          </div>
```

```
          <table class="table table-striped">

              <tr>

                  <td>Nome</td>

                  <td>Data</td>

              </tr>

              <tr ng-repeat="aniversario in aniversarios | searchDatesBetween:fromDate:toDate">

                  <td>{{aniversario.name}}</td>

                  <td>{{aniversario.date}}</td>

              </tr>

          </table>
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: You may get more answers if you reduce your code to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and format it correctly. Also "does not work" or "cannot render" is not a sufficient problem description. Include any error messages. Also check the browser console or any log files.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere you are using the directive in your view,

Also you need to inject `ui.mask` as a dependency to your module

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/39x5fY?p=preview)**